# Nextjs boiler plate development server giving error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am just starting to learn next.js. I installed `create-next-app` tried starting a development server without changing any code provided by boilerplate. I get this error

```
./styles/globals.css
Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom <App>. Due to the Global nature of stylesheets, and to avoid conflicts, Please move all first-party global CSS imports to pages/_app.js. Or convert the import to Component-Level CSS (CSS Modules).
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/css-global
Location: pages\_app.js
```

I am just starting with nextjs so I do not have any other information besides this and I have not changed any code

commands I used

```
npx create-next-app next_js_list
cd next_js_list
npm run dev
```

This is the package.json I have

```
{
  "name": "next_js_list",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "11.1.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.1.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same for me, looks like an error with the new next.js version 11.1.1, just go back to 11.1.0, and will be ok, a fix will be coming shortly

Comment: Same here defo 11.1.1 is broken and 11.1.0 working. Royal pain in the but.

Comment: Yes 11.1.1 was the problem now they have fixed it in 11.1.2 Here is a link to Github Discussion. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/28632#issuecomment-908763741